# Can you control write speed to DynamoDB using Boto3?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-auto-scaling

I need to write to DynamoDB which is Autoscaling enabled, my goal is:

- best utilize provisioned capacity according to its changing capacity (by Autoscaling) without or with little "throttled writes"

We are using batch_writer() at the moment, the problem with it is there's no response like what BatchWriteItem does, so you can adjust capacity based on response. But BatchWriteItem has its own problem -- it has a limit of 25 items per request, even I have many threads, it's probably not quick enough for my needs, I need about 10000 WCU / second at maximum.

What would you suggest?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem right now. Have you ever figured out a solution?

Comment: Sorry mate, not yet